# XML XBRL _ Can we use a freeware XML parser (BaseX) to parse XBRL data since XBRL is XML-based?

Tags: xml, database, xbrl

It all boils down to a very critical question on parsing `XML` data!

- Can we parse [XBRL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL) (which is XML-based) to extract data from a [database](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1009672/000119312514065056/crr-20131231.xml)?

**The reason** i am submitting this theoretical question (which requires technical capacity on XML) is that software houses are putting a separate **[price tag](https://shop.altova.com/category.asp?category_name=RAPTORXML)** (please check that previous link) between `XML parsers` and `XBRL parsers`! That definitely raises a red flag.

- Can we use a freeware like `BaseX` which is designed to query `XML` to parse an [XBRL Instance document](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1009672/000119312514065056/0001193125-14-065056-index.htm) and extract data. If not why since XBRL is XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All XBRL is XML, so, at a base level, yes, you can.

However, XBRL imposes additional semantics and validations on top of XML specific to the XBRL spec. Therefore, valid XML is not necessarily valid XBRL. Vendors are putting a separate price tag on XBRL because of the semantic and validity rules imposed by the XBRL spec. Valid XBRL is also valid XML, but valid XML is not necessarily valid XBRL.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with XBRL is that the main thing you get out of the XML, is a set of facts with a lot of codes attached to them. Those codes are meaningless without parsing the taxonomy, which contains all the definitions.

The taxonomy unfortunately also contains things like formula's (yes, really), presentations (what goes where) and other "helpful" additions that complicate things endlessly. Apart from that, the standard uses Linkbases for everything. A pretty standard taxonomy can easily contain over 2000 separate files.

Yes, you can use an XML parser for this, but it won't give back anything meaningful. For that, you have to parse the instances AND the taxonomy. And that is unfortunately not available for low pricing.

You can take a look at a tool like Arelle from www.openfiling.info (the open source part of the EU XBRL filing project) - that should give you an idea why normal XML parsers won't help. Link: www.openfiling.info/arelle/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. Currently my company does it with eXist-db but the same rules are applicable to BaseX, Sedna or Marklogic.

You will have to master XPath 2.0 and know a bit of XQuery, and avoid doing namespace specific queries.

I think you need to query data from XBRL instance documents. This can be done in two steps:
1. Obtain the context id you want to query
2. Search the fact element on this context

This query can do it with a single call:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare default element namespace"http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";

declare function local:for-context($node as node(),$ent as xs:string,$start as xs:string,$end as xs:string) as xs:boolean {
    let $cid := $node/@contextRef
    let $ctx := $node/../context[ @id = $cid ]
    return if ( $ctx 
                and not(exists($ctx/entity/segment)) 
                and $ctx/entity/identifier=$ent 
                and $ctx/period/startDate=$start 
                and $ctx/period/endDate=$end ) then true() else false()
    };

let $id := request:get-parameter( 'id', '0001173514' ) 
let $startDate := request:get-parameter( 'startdate', '2013-04-01' ) 
let $endDate := request:get-parameter( 'enddate', '2013-06-30' ) 
let $fact := request:get-parameter( 'fact', 'NonoperatingIncomeExpense' ) 

let $q := concat( "/*/*:", $fact, "[ local:for-context(., $id, $startDate, $endDate) ]" ) 

return util:eval($q)
```

It receives a company ID, start date, end date and the fact name, and returns the value from the instance document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard XML parser to parse the XBRL instance document. However (via the Wikipedia page you cited):

> In typical usage, XBRL consists of an XBRL instance, containing primarily the business facts being reported, and a collection of taxonomies (called a Discoverable Taxonomy Set (DTS)), which define metadata about these facts, such as what the facts mean and how they relate to one another. XBRL uses XML Schema, XLink, and XPointer standards.

So to actually process the XBRL document's content, you will probably need to be able to handle XLinks and XPointers, and you will need to know how to retrieve, interpret, and apply the metadata from the DTS.

As far as extracting data from a database goes: Unless XBRL is acting as a query language, it would seem to me that in this case you would be creating a new instance document rather than parsing an existing one. That's the opposite of parsing. Most parsers do come with XML serializers that handle the syntax details, but it'd be your responsibility to construct an appropriate document that has the right semantics.

I haven't looked at the products at all, but I suspect that these points are where an XBRL package differs from basic XML tools -- it contains additional logic to manipulate the semantics for this particular language.